# EmguCV hand dectection

Tags: c#, detection, emgucv, motion-detection

I am creating a detection program in C# in a Windows Form Application and I am using the C# Wrapper EmguCV to handle the OpenCV library. In the Emgu package there are HaarCascades (which are XML files used for template matching) for the face, eyes, mouth, etc but there isn't one for the hand. I have read up on how to create a file for the template to be created but I need a lot of images for it to work. So what I was wondering was is there a program about that can take in a video file or a feed from a webcam and take a still at each frame and sort the images into the positive and negative images that I will need. All I need is the program to get images in order to create the file, the rest I have read on how to do it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV or EmguCV to create a program to create images from each frame of a video but for the program to be able to detect positive and negative images you would need to already have a trained classifier to recognise the shape of the hand, which is exactly what you want to do.
You would have to sort out the images generated manually and then build your hard cascade for the hand.
Regards
Shivam